# htaccess - I change rewritebase but still needs public folder in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

My index.php is in public folder and in my .htaccess file I say that rewrite base is the public directory. But when I open the cms.test, it gives me cms folders.. for the use index php, still I need to go public folder..

here is my .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /var/www/cms/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: @tereško it based on mvc system actually, are sure that it's not bond with mvc tag ?

Comment: It's about URL routing and htaccess. This has nothing to do with MVC. What you are running it all on is also based on C. So why didn't you also tag it with C? And probably also MySQL.

Answer (score -2):

Set your public folder to be the root directory

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /var/www/cms/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

Set your public folder to be the root directory

Comment: Was is different between your answer and what they said they've tried?

Comment: it's not root directory actually, it's just a another folder in root directory. I checked the other mvc frameoworks, how they redirect the http request to index.php but as I understand they uses sample server.php for that.. I just wondering is that possible to redirect request directly to the index.php without any server file